# Matching two like indexes with .map in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, array.prototype.map

this is my first time posting so I'll try to make things as clear as I can. I'm working on an assignment with nested arrays and I've sort of hit a wall. I'm trying to write a function that will loop through a set of nested arrays until it finds an item whose index matches that of the function argument. What I'm stumped on is how to write out the code to compare the current item in the iteration to the "masterIndex" of the function. Ultimately what I want is to create a new array made from items who's indexes match the index of the "name" given in the function's argument. Does anybody have any ideas on how to do this?

This is the code I have so far.

```
let masterArray = ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4"]

let childArray = [
[data1, data2, data3, data4],
[data1, data2, data3, data4],
[data1, data2, data3, data4],
[data1, data2, data3, data4]
]

let matchingData = (name) => {
  let masterIndex = masterArray.indexOf(name)
  let foundData = childArray.map((subArray) => {
    subArray.map((singleData) => {
      
    })
  })

}
```

Edited for clarity:

Comment: do you have some *real* data and the wanted result?

Comment: Ideally what I am trying to do is create a new array with items whose indexes match that of the given "name" from the masterArray, and then return the length of that new array.

Comment: @AJ_F Please demonstrate the output. It's unclear your requirement.